# init script of debian package not working correcly in different computers in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, packaging, init.d

I created a Debian single binary package (.deb) for a software project to install the application as a service in ubuntu. `dpkg --install` package installation is successful in the computer I used to create the .deb package but I tried with different PC with same environment (all dependencies are installed in these 2 PCs) installation was success and all files installed to correct file locations. 
I triggered `service serviceName start` to start the service. Service successfully started but process is stopping instantly (**Log message show 0xff signal received**).
I tried to start the process using the installed binary file in installation location (/opt/xxxx/bin directory) then process working properly. 
below is the init script (the script place to /etc/init.d/ directory) and is this a problem with the init script ?

summary of steps

1. create debian package (used dh_make, dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot related commands)
2. install in the same PC, installation success and service start-run-stop correctly
3. try in different PC, installation success, service started but stop instantly.

below is the init script

```
#!/bin/bash
# cscore daemon
# chkconfig: 345 20 80
# description: Daemon service (cscore) for cscore ubuntu 12.04
# processname: cscore

DAEMON_PATH="/opt/xxx/bin"

DAEMON=cscore
NAME=cscore
DESC="Daemon service (cscore) for CoreScanner in ubuntu 12.04"
PIDFILE=/var/run/$NAME.pid
SCRIPTNAME=/etc/init.d/$NAME

case "$1" in
start)
    printf "%-50s" "Starting $NAME..."
    cd $DAEMON_PATH
    PID=`$DAEMON > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!`
    #echo "Saving PID" $PID " to " $PIDFILE
        if [ -z $PID ]; then
            printf "%s\n" "Fail"
        else
            echo $PID > $PIDFILE
            printf "%s\n" "Ok"
        fi
;;

status)
        printf "%-50s" "Checking $NAME..."
        if [ -f $PIDFILE ]; then
            PID=`cat $PIDFILE`
            if [ -z "`ps axf | grep ${PID} | grep -v grep`" ]; then
                printf "%s\n" "Process dead but pidfile exists"
            else
                echo "Running"
            fi
        else
            printf "%s\n" "Service not running"
        fi
;;

stop)
        printf "%-50s" "Stopping $NAME"
            PID=`cat $PIDFILE`
            cd $DAEMON_PATH
        if [ -f $PIDFILE ]; then
            kill -HUP $PID
            printf "%s\n" "Ok"
            rm -f $PIDFILE
        else
            printf "%s\n" "pidfile not found"
        fi
;;

restart)
    $0 stop
    $0 start
;;

*)
        echo "Usage: $0 {status|start|stop|restart}"
        exit 1
esac
```

Comment: First, /opt is "OK" but not really used in Ubuntu. This location was used in Fedora for a while, but most distros are going over to /usr/local. Second, there is really no need to "cd $DAEMON_PATH" , just call your program with the full path. Last, in your start) case , I do not see you starting anything (unless $DAEMON is starting something). Just start your program, then set $PID. Again, I highly suggest you read the packaging documentation if you ever wish to include this program in a ppa or the Debian (Ubuntu) repos. Non-standard packaging causes headaches.

Comment: Of course, if you really wish a Ubuntu package, consider using upstart.

Comment: @bodhi: Thanks and I welcome your suggestions to dig the issue. I this packaging I just need to create a package to install the application into other PC (not for repos). First I will correct the mention lines in the scripts. -Thanks

Comment: @DigTheCode, Have you tried change to root  `sudo su` then run it as `/opt/../bin/..` ?